# Maximum occurring at all points in a set

Tags: optimization, supremum-and-infimum

Is there any term for "sets where maximum of a mathematical expression in attained"? I just want to know if the set has any specific name. The set is infinite (do not consider discrete points). The maximum is achieved in a subset of parameter space.

Answer (score 1):

> In mathematics, the **argument of the maximum** (abbreviated **arg max** or **argmax**) is the set of points of the given argument for which the given function attains its maximum value.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max).

Notation-wise, it looks like 
$$E = \operatorname*{arg\,max}_{x\in \mathbb{R}} f(x)$$